# Towers of Hanoi: Moving Rings from Peg to Peg

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console

Expanding on my previous post, I am still writing Towers of Hanoi. After having a wonderful solution explained of how to draw the rings on the pegs, I still have one question that I have been fiddling with for quite awhile now.

Here is my PegClass:

```
namespace Towers_Of_Hanoi
{
    class PegClass
    {
        private int pegheight; 
        private int y = 3;
        int[] rings = new int[0];
        public PegClass()
        { 
            //this is the default constructor 
        }
        public PegClass(int height)
        { 
            pegheight = height; 
        }

        // other user defined functions 
        public void AddRing(int size)
        { 
            Array.Resize (ref rings, rings.Length + 2);
            rings[rings.Length - 1] = size;
        }

        public void DrawPeg(int x, int numberOfRings = 0)
        { 
            for (int i = pegheight; i >= 1; i--) 
            {
                string halfRing = new string (' ', i);
                if (numberOfRings > 0) 
                { 
                    if (i <= numberOfRings)
                        halfRing = new string ('-', numberOfRings - i + 1);

                }
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x - halfRing.Length * 2 + i + (halfRing.Contains("-") ? (-i + halfRing.Length) : 0), y);
                Console.WriteLine(halfRing + "|" + halfRing);
                y++;
            }
            if (x < 7) {
                x = 7;
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition (x - 7, y); //print the base of the peg
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my main method.

```
namespace Tower_of_hanoi
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PegClass myPeg = new PegClass(8);
            PegClass myPeg2 = new PegClass(8);
            PegClass myPeg3 = new PegClass(8);
            DrawBoard(myPeg, myPeg2, myPeg3);
            Console.WriteLine ("\t\t\nWelcome to kTowers!");

            while (true) 
            {
                string input = "\nWhat peg do you want to move to commander?";
                Console.WriteLine (input);
                if (input == "2")
                {
                    myPeg.DrawPeg (2);
                }
                Console.ReadLine ();          
            }
        }

        public static void DrawBoard(PegClass peg1,PegClass peg2,PegClass peg3)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            peg1.DrawPeg(20,1);
            peg2.DrawPeg(40,2);
            peg3.DrawPeg(60,4);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the current output:

```
                |                   |                   |        
                |                   |                   |       
                |                   |                   |      
                |                   |                   |     
                |                   |                  -|-
                |                   |                 --|--
                |                  -|-               ---|---
               -|-                --|--             ----|----
         ----------------    ----------------    ----------------
```

My question remains, how does one move the '-' characters from peg to peg when asked for a prompt. I've tried tweaking it for hours and still couldn't figure it out.

Thank you in advance, youmeoutside

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please, next time you post a question, can you properly indent it? Not only will it help people to read and understand your code, it'll make it tidier for you as well and anyone else that reads it.

Comment: To understand your question a bit better, do you want to move the pegs on the original output of the Console? Or do you want to redraw a new peg system after every input?

Comment: You must create the rings as separate objects. As it shows now you have 3 rings with the same width, this is not the towers of hanoi, this is something different. So "the height" of a peg is given by how many rings you have on it but you need to instantiate the rings as concrete objects that have a width.

Comment: @Rob, Sorry for the slight inconvenience Rob, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ruskin, I want to be able to move the pegs on the original output of the console. So for instance, the first peg would have 3 rings, then you have to move the rings accordingly to the other pegs.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I will take a gander at your solution. It looks like something I can learn from. Thank you for taking the time to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have manifested the rings as just "how many rings are on this peg" but that won't be enough.

For instance, if you have 8 rings you will represent one ring with width 1, one with width 2, one with 3, etc. up to one with 8.

In your image you have 3 rings with width of 1 (the top one on each peg), 2 with width 2 (the second ring on the two pegs that have multiple rings), and so on. This is incorrect and the reason for why your code does this is that it have no notion of "how wide should this particular ring be", instead it draws the top ring with width 1, the one below it with width 2, etc.

Instead here is a very simple set of objects to represent the rings and pegs and the operation to move from one to the other:

```
public void MoveRing(Peg fromPeg, Peg toPeg)
{
    toPeg.Push(fromPeg.Pop());
}

public class Peg : Stack<Ring>
{
}

public struct Ring
{
    public int Width { get; }
    public Ring(int width) { Width = width; }
}
```

To create 3 pegs and stack 8 rings on the first peg you could use this code:

```
const int pegCount = 3;
const int ringCount = 8;

var pegs = Enumerable.Range(1, pegCount).Select(_ => new Peg()).ToList();

foreach (var ring in Enumerable.Range(1, ringCount).Select(width => new Ring(ringCount + 1 - width)))
    pegs[0].Push(ring);
```

To draw them I took the liberty of fleshing out a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that draws them to demonstrate but you could easily adapt this to the console code you have now:

```
void Main()
{
    const int pegCount = 3;
    const int ringCount = 8;

    var pegs = Enumerable.Range(1, pegCount).Select(_ => new Peg()).ToList();

    foreach (var ring in Enumerable.Range(1, ringCount).Select(width => new Ring(ringCount + 1 - width)))
        pegs[0].Push(ring);

    DrawPegs(pegs);
    MoveRing(pegs[0], pegs[1]);
    DrawPegs(pegs);
}

public void MoveRing(Peg fromPeg, Peg toPeg)
{
    toPeg.Push(fromPeg.Pop());
}

public class Peg : Stack<Ring>
{
}

public struct Ring
{
    public int Width { get; }
    public Ring(int width) { Width = width; }
}

public void DrawPegs(IEnumerable<Peg> pegs)
{
    var bitmaps = pegs.Select(peg => DrawPeg(peg));
    Util.HorizontalRun(true, bitmaps).Dump();
}

public Bitmap DrawPeg(Peg peg)
{
    const int width = 200;
    const int height = 300;
    const int pegWidth = 6;
    const int ringHeight = 20;
    const int ringWidthFactor = 10;
    const int ringGapHeight = 3;

    var result = new Bitmap(width, height);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.White);

        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, width / 2 - pegWidth/2, 0, pegWidth, height);
        int y = height;
        foreach (var ring in peg.Reverse())
        {
            y -= ringHeight;
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, width / 2 - ring.Width * ringWidthFactor, y, 2 * ring.Width * ringWidthFactor, ringHeight);
            y -= ringGapHeight;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The output:

[image: pegs and rings]

Comment: This is a very good solution. I applaud you for taking the time to help me understand this. But how would make this not using any of the IEnumerables? Is there no other way to do it but that?

Comment: If you're always going to have 3 pegs, just make the methods that take pegs as a collection take pegs specifically, like `Peg a, Peg b, Peg c` (probably with better names though).